# Resultset overflow occurred jpivot

Tags: pentaho, dice, mondrian, slicers

I have created cube in PSW and published it over BI server. Using this cube I have created jPivot view (slice & dice).
When I try to expand the view it gives me "Resultset overflow occured" message. Logs are not showing any error.

I am using PSW CE -8.1 and Pentaho Server CE 8.1

Total records in fact table is 25 million

Below is done to optimise the performance:

1. Indexes are added in dimensions and fact tables
2. Pentaho query time out increased
    file name - pentahoobjects.spring.xml
3. Tomcat time out increased

server.xml -> change connectiontimeout to 0

4. Below mondrian.properties are changed (mondrian/mondrian.properties)

   ```
   mondrian.result.limit=0

   mondrian.olap.case.sensitive=false

   mondrian.native.crossjoin.enable=true

   mondrian.native.ExpandNonNative=false
   ```

Please suggest what is wrong or any other property needs to be optimised.

Thanks,
Mayuri

Comment: That is almost certainly not the error you are getting. Show the full error message as formatted text that can be copied and searched. You should also show your [mcve]. If this is only about DB scaling you might have better luck researching over on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, this isnt error as for some dimensions its working fine. However, not for all dimensions. I will check dba.stackexchange.com